# predicted_proba in multi-class logistic classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 5 classes as the output which represent the predicted **grade** of a student - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

When I input my values, with predict_proba, i get the probability of each class.

eg.

**class 1:** 0.1 **class 2:** 0.4: **class 3:** 0.3 **class 4**: 0.05 **class 5:** 0.15

However, the only thing I get from this is that the prediction is: **class 2**, as the probability is highest. How would I convert these probabilities to a more specific prediction, for example, 2.4 or 2.9? where 2 is equal to **class 2**.

Would this be possible? If so, how?

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: [`model.predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict)?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that only gives me the prediction of class 2, it doesnt give me decimals or anything more specific

Comment: What do you mean "more specific"? How can it get more specific than `2`?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense, because *classification* problems map from the feature space to a finite (esp. small), discrete set.  You don't classify as "partly in one, and partly in the other" bucket.

Comment: @apnorton not partly in one, and partly in another, its more like which way it leans more towards to based on the probabilities.

Comment: @apnorton i was able to accomplish this in R using the nnet (neural network) package. not sure if i can do this here though ;/

Comment: i was able to accomplish this in R using the nnet (neural network) package. not sure if i can do this here though ;/ @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga more specific as since the probabilities for each class vary, if for example class 2 was predicted, but class 3 was almost equal but just slightly less, the prediction would be like 2.9 or something if that makes sense. as in which way the prediction leans more to

Comment: It sounds like you want regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one fast way to do this:

```
probs = LRC.predict_proba(x)
class_indexes = np.argmax(probs,axis=1)
max_probs = probs[np.arange(len(x)),class_indexes]
class_output = lrc.classes_[class_indexes]
class_prob_list = zip(class_output,max_probs)
print [str(cls)+'.'+str(prob) for cls,prob in class_prob_list]
```

Comment: thanks for this, however, len_data does not seem to be defined?

Comment: the last line is also not very clear, with cls and prob not defined ;/

Comment: alright well i tested it - seems to me all its doing is stringing the class with the corresponding probability, doesn't really tell me which way the classes lean towards ;/

Comment: You have to train a regression model for this. Also can you put these requirements in question description

Comment: no worries - thanks for the effort, i marked you correct for helping anyways :)